# Image disappears quickly instead of fadeOut

Tags: jquery, css

hey guys i am trying to work on a css3 fullscreen slider. Now the problem is whenever i  do an image fadeOut it suddenly hides like if i have coded the hide() method..
here is the code,
the css

```
   body {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #backgroundImageContainer {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
    }
    .backgroundImages {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1; 
    }
    .animationZoomIN {

        -webkit-transition: all 5.3s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 5.3s ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 5.3s ease-out;
        transition: all 5.3s ease-out;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.17);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.17);
        -o-transform: scale(1.17);
        transform: scale(1.17);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.17);
    }
    #thumbsList {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        margin-top: 11px;
        margin-right: 11px;
        color: white;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 13px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    #thumbsList li {
        float: left;
    }
```

the javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.backgroundImages').addClass('animationZoomIN');
        $('.backgroundImages').bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () {


            $('.backgroundImages').fadeOut(1000);});
    });
```

And the html

```
   <div id="backgroundImageContainer">
    <img class="backgroundImages" src="wallpaper-452100.png" />

</div>
<ul id="thumbsList">
    <li>Steam Punk</li>
    <li>Car</li>

</ul>
```

Notice the .backgroundImages fadeOut method is not working, it suddently makes the image disappear.
can you guys tell me where i am wrong?thanks.

Ok here is a Fiddle, 
**http://jsfiddle.net/4xymL/**

i don't know the image is somehow not diplaying, try to use some sample image please, thanks. soo much.

Comment: A http://www.jsfiddle.net will help you get answers.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand.:(

Comment: how can i then fade out image after animation?

Comment: Sure,let me try to Fiddle it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4xymL/

Comment: you didn't include jquery, also there is a broken link to an image

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/guJQ7/2/ ok i get what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the opacity as shown in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xymL/4/) and then fade out after a delay of 5s (this depends on what you have mentioned in zoom in css.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $('.backgroundImages').addClass('animationZoomIN');
     $('.backgroundImages').bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () {


         $('.backgroundImages').css("opacity", 0).delay(5000).fadeOut();
     });
 });
```

Updated to fade out since changing opacity alone will not remove the image, it will still be present and can be verified by right clicking.